# How to make an existing navbar with position fixed?

Tags: html, css, frontend, navbar, human-computer-interface

I made the following nav bar for the website of a client. But just at the end Client told me to make this navbar fixed on top, Obviously it will take a lot of time and effort to build a navbar from scratch just to make it fixed on top. Is there any way I can make my existing navbar fixed on top by modifying CSS?

HTML:

```css
   body
    {
        margin: 0;
        background: #222;
        font-weight: 300;
        background-image: url('bg.jpeg');

    }

    header
    {
        background: #d9c2ac;
        position: relative;
    }

    header::after
    {
        content: '';
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    nav
    {
        float: left;
    }

    nav ul
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    nav li
    {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 70px;
        padding-top: 30px;
        position: relative;
    }

    nav ul li  a
    {
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    nav a:hover
    {

    }


    nav a::before
    {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 5px;
        width: 0%;
        background-color: #444;

        transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;


    }

    nav ul li:last-child
    {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom:  0;
    margin: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    }

    nav ul li:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    nav a:hover::before
    {
        width: 100%;
    }

    nav ul li:last-child
    {
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
        <div class="container" id="#home">
            <nav>
                <ul> 
                    <li id="login"> <a href="#login" style="text-align: left;"> Login/Register                        </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#home"> Home </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#about"> About </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#services"> Services </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#Products"> Products </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#contact"> Contact Us </a></li>
                     <li> <form class="form"> <input type="text" name="Search"                                            placeholder="Search"> </form> </li>
                 </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change some css

```
header
 {
   background: #d9c2ac;
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 99; //Change as per your requirement.
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the changes mentioned if it works for you. I think it may solve your problem.

**CSS** and 
**HTML**

```css
body
{
    margin: 0;
    background: #222;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-image: url('bg.jpeg');

}

header
{
    background: #d9c2ac;
    position: fixed; //Add this
    top: 0;//Add this
    left: 0;//Add this
    z-index: 1000;//Add this
    width: 100%;//Add this
}
  
header::after
{
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

nav
{
    float: left;
}

nav ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li  a
{
color: #444;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
}

nav a:hover
{

}


nav a::before
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #444;

    transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;


}

nav ul li:last-child
{
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom:  0;
margin: 15px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding: 0;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
nav a:hover::before
{
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul li:last-child
{
    margin-right: auto;
}
//Add this property to your content div
#content {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 55px; // Height of your navbar
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container" id="#home">
        <nav>
            <ul> 
                <li id="login"> <a href="#login" style="text-align: left;"> Login/Register </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#home"> Home </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#about"> About </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#services"> Services </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#Products"> Products </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#contact"> Contact Us </a></li>
                 <li> <form class="form"> <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Search"> </form> </li>
             </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header> 

<div id="content">Your body content here</div>
```